# Attempting to upload or update sketch or firmware always fails

Tags: linux, arduino, gnome, arduino-ide

My host is popOS and I suspect that matters here.

I plug in my Arduino and see the device show up:

```
$ ls /dev | grep -i -E 'acm|usb'
ttyACM0
usb
```

The default sketch is working as the power LED and Blink program seems to all be working fine.

Arduino IDE detects it. I attempt to upload a simple sketch and get this ambiguous error:

```
Performing 1200-bps touch reset on serial port /dev/ttyACM0
"/home/$USER/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/rp2040tools/1.0.6/rp2040load" -v -D "/tmp/$USER/sketches/A5EA0D0CAA8498593C6DBE39B6DE9B19/sketch_sep11a.ino.elf"
rp2040load 1.0.6 - compiled with go1.16.2
.....................
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

Checking `/dev` again:

```
ls /dev | grep -i -E 'acm|usb'
usb
```

Seems to indicate that the device has disappeared. The Blink program has stopped but the Power LED is still on.

At the same time, in the *Files* app. The SD Card called `RPI-RP2` is now mounted.

I can easily reproduce this by pushing the hardware reset button on the Arduino.

I suspect that there's something with popOS going on that's forcing the SD Card to mount and thus remove the TTY before the IDE can finish uploading?

Here is what `dmesg` says while all of this is happening

```
[11623.779472] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 34
[11624.098516] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
[11624.259724] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=2e8a, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 1.00
[11624.259734] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[11624.259738] usb 1-6: Product: RP2 Boot
[11624.259740] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Raspberry Pi
[11624.259743] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: E0C9125B0D9B
[11624.263943] usb-storage 1-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[11624.264150] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-6:1.0
[11625.275162] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     RPI      RP2              3    PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[11625.275576] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[11625.275929] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 262144 512-byte logical blocks: (134 MB/128 MiB)
[11625.276389] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[11625.276391] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[11625.276755] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[11625.276755] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11625.282206]  sdb: sdb1
[11625.282535] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And `lsof`

```
$ lsof /dev/ttyACM0 
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
serial-mo 28185    $USER    3u   CHR  166,0      0t0 1814 /dev/ttyACM0
$ ps auxww | grep 28185
$USER   28185  0.0  0.0 1075580 4160 ?        Sl   19:52   0:00 /home/$USER/.arduino15/packages/builtin/tools/serial-monitor/0.13.0/serial-monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an SD card but a UF2 bootloader presenting itself as a mass storage device.

This behavior is normal if there is no sketch running. There must be a sketch which invokes the reset on 1200 baud connection.

Hit the reset button before the IDE attempts to upload. Once a good sketch is uploaded the reset will be handled automatically.